# Multiple actions on a list

Tags: c#

I have this list.I want to have distinct values based on category sorted by the Order .Can someone please tell me how can I do it.

```
public class Item
    {
        public string URL{ get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }        
        public string Order{ get; set; }


    }

    var Test = new List<Items>

    var groups = Test.Select(g => g.category).Distinct();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more what you intend to do?

Comment: I want to first select the distinct values in the Test list and then sort them by the order .

Comment: You are now selecting distinct categories.

Comment: Yeah and after selecting distinct categories I also want to sort them using the order.

Comment: Does a Category have an Order (and is it IComparable too)?

Comment: order is just a string field in the Test list

Comment: Please improve the question. Show what `Item` is and describe the desired output better.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = Test
    .GroupBy(g => g.Category)
    .Select(g => new
                 {
                     Category = g.Key,
                     Items = g.OrderBy(i => i.Order)
                 })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Category)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Items)
    .ToList();
```

or, essentially the same thing in this case:

```
Test.OrderBy(it => it.Category).ThenBy(it => it.Order)
```

The first code you can take out the SelectMany if you want a list of groups with sub-lists of items in that category sorted by Order.

Comment: In this case it will first group by the category value and then order it by the category value itself..I want to group it by category value and then sort it using the order value of the Test list.

Comment: @user505210: Updated it. Something like this?